# Audio transformer power level

Tags: power, transformer, audio, driver, specifications

I am going to use SP-69.

https://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/SP-69.pdf

Its power level is 50mW.

I am going to use DRV135 to drive audio transformer(SP-69).

Output voltage of the DRV135 is 7Vrms(19.8Vp-p).

https://www.ti.com/product/DRV135

Can I use SP-69 to get 7Vrms?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the title I'm going to take a wag that you're asking about maximum power level delivered by the transformer. If we assume everything to be the simplest possible case, then we'll consider the load to be a simple resistor. Power delivered by the transformer to the resistor is P = V^2 / R = 7^2 / 600 = 82mW. That's more than the 50mW rating, so not a good idea.